# ES6 modules import don't work without (.js) file extension

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

**index.js**

```
import { DomEvent } from "./core/dom";
```

I have dom.js file in core directory but ES6 would not load it until explicitly defile it like

```
import { DomEvent } from "./core/dom.js";
```

is there any way to load it without file extension?

Comment: thats part of the spec. You need to specify the full file path.

Comment: In what environment does your code run (browser, nodes, something else)? Are you using a transpiler?

Comment: thank you @Lux, I am using typescript to compile index.js. is there any option there to add an extension for me

Comment: actually I want to debug typescript code in a browser using source map

Comment: this is the actual issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577